# PHP - Get the key of a subarray based on a value within

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the key of a subarray based on a value in that subarray. So, based on the example below, how can I return the key of the array containing 'apple'?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [fruit] => apple 
        [colour] => green 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [fruit] => banana 
        [colour] => yellow 
    ) 
)
```

So logically, something like:

```
if ('apple' is in $subarray) {
    echo $subarray_key;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use a loop to check all the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your array is stored in `$arr` variable, you can do

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array('apple',$value){
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: a closing bracket (for the if) is missing..

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array('apple',$value) ) {
        echo $key;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach($array as $key => $val){
      if($val == 'apple'){
           print $key;
      }
 }
```

You can use array keys and do some other stuff but for the most part you're going to end up just iterating through the array anyways

Comment: I guess `$val` will be an array which contains the value 'apple' not the value itself